# Thread interruption from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm creating 9 threads using something like this (all threads will process infinity loop)

```
void printStr();

thread func_thread(printStr);
void printStr() {

    while (true) {
        cout << "1\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }

}
```

I also create 10th thread to control them. How would I stop or kill any of this 9 threads from my 10th? Or suggest another mechanism please.

Comment: Have you looked at boost::threads?

Comment: C++11 threads are non interruptable

Comment: @OldProgrammer any other solutions?

Comment: What does "control them" mean? How do you "control" your main program?

Comment: @KerrekSB i mean, if I print 'stop 1', first thread will come to sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, for example, atomic boolean:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

std::atomic<bool> run(true);

void foo()
{
  while(run.load(memory_order_relaxed)) 
  { 
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<thread> v;
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    v.push_back(std::thread(foo));

  run.store(false, memory_order_relaxed);
  for(auto& th : v)
    th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT (in response of your comment): you can also use a mutual variable, protected by a mutex.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

void foo(mutex& m, bool& b)
{
  while(1)
  { 
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    lock_guard<mutex> l(m);
    if(!b)
      break;
  }
}

void bar(mutex& m, bool& b)
{
  lock_guard<mutex> l(m);
  b = false;
}

int main()
{
  vector<thread> v;
  bool b = true;
  mutex m;

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    v.push_back(thread(foo, ref(m), ref(b)));

  v.push_back(thread(bar, ref(m), ref(b)));

  for(auto& th : v)
    th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is in the post, I've edited it because the code is too long for a comment ;o

Answer (score 2):

It is never appropriate to kill a thread directly, you should instead send a signal to the thread to tell it to stop by itself. This will allow it to clean up and finish properly.

The mechanism you use is up to you and depends on the situation. It can be an event or a state checked periodically from within the thread.

Comment: could u give me an example? im really new to this and looked a lot already

Comment: @AntiClimacus just gave you a way to signal the thread with an atomic<bool>!

Answer (score 2):

std::thread objects are non - interruptible. You will have to use another thread library like boost or pthreads to accomplish your task. Please do  note that killing threads is dangerous operation.

To illustrate how to approach this problem in pthread using cond_wait and cond_signal,In the main section you could create another thread called monitor thread that will keep waiting on a signal from one of the 9 thread.

```
pthread_mutex_t monMutex;////mutex 
pthread_cond_t condMon;////condition variable
```

Creating threads:

```
pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*) malloc (9* sizeof(pthread_t)); 
for (int t=0; t < 9;t++)
            {
                argPtr[t].threadId=t;
                KillAll=false;
                rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, &(launchInThread), (void *)&argPtr[t]);
                if (rc){
                    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                    exit(-1);
                }

            }
```

creating monitor thread:

```
  monitorThreadarg.threadArray=threads;//pass reference of thread array to monitor thread
  monitorThreadarg.count=9;
            pthread_t monitor_thread;
            rc= pthread_create(&monitor_thread,NULL,&monitorHadle,(void * )(&monitorThreadArg));
                if (rc){
                    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                    exit(-1);
            }
```

then wait on 9 threads and monitor thread:

```
for (s=0; s < 9;s++)
        {
                pthread_join(threads[s], &status);
        }

            pthread_cond_signal(&condMon);// if all threads finished successfully then signal monitor thread too 
            pthread_join(monitor_thread, &status);
            cout << "joined with monitor thread"<<endl;
```

The monitor function would be something like this:

```
void* monitorHadle(void* threadArray)
{
pthread_t* temp =static_cast<monitorThreadArg*> (threadArray)->threadArray;
int number =static_cast<monitorThreadArg*> (threadArray)->count;
pthread_mutex_lock(&monMutex);
mFlag=1;//check so that monitor threads has initialised
pthread_cond_wait(&condMon,&monMutex);// wait for signal 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&monMutex);
void * status;
if (KillAll==true)
{
printf("kill all \n");
for  (int i=0;i<number;i++)
{
    pthread_cancel(temp[i]);
}
}
```

}

the function what will be launched over 9 threads should be something like this:

```
  void launchInThread( void *data)
  {
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    while(1)
        {
            try 
            {
                throw("exception whenever your criteria is met");

            }
            catch (string x)
            {
                cout << "exception form  !! "<< pthread_self() <<endl;
                KillAll=true;
                while(!mFlag);//wait till monitor thread has initialised
                pthread_mutex_lock(&monMutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&condMon);//signail monitor thread
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&monMutex);
                pthread_exit((void*) 0);
            }
        }
 }
```

Please note that if you dont't put :
         thread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL); 
after launching your thread then your threads wouldn't terminate on thread_cancel call.
It is necessary that you clean up up all the data before you cancel a thread.